# Bottomsheetdialogfragment with Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to make a complex Bottomsheetdialogfragment inside which there is a recyclerview. I also need the Bottomsheetdialogfragment to rise and fall when the recyclerview is spinning all the way down or up.
However, right now the Bottomsheetdialogfragment is only being lifted from the scroll of the recyclerview, but is not being released. But the main problem is that after opening the Bottomsheetdialogfragment, while I'm waiting for the data, the place where the recyclerview should be is just empty and I see the bottom fragment.I also don't understand why recyclerview doesn't scroll to the end and the bottom item is visible by half.
Code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottom_sheet_dialog" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_back"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:rotation="-90"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/slim_arrow"
            app:tint="@color/appBlack" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_line"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_sheet_line_radius"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Выбрать дату и время"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_sheet_line" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_current_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_next_month"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="НОЯБРЬ" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_next_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:textColor="@color/grayLight"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="ДЕКАБРЬ" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.kizitonwose.calendar.view.WeekCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        app:cv_daySize="seventhWidth"
        app:cv_dayViewResource="@layout/calendar_weekend_res"
        app:cv_orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_current_month" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rc_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/booking_times_item" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/lProceedOrder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/shadow_gradient"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_booking_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/text_insurance"
            android:textColor="@color/appBlack"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shadow" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBlock"
            style="@style/GreenDeclineButtonBlock"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_booking_description"
            tools:text="@string/hire_block"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

My Fragment

```
private val binding by lazy {(FragmentBookingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater))}
private val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd")
private var presenter: BookingContracts.Presenter? = null
private var recyclerAdapter: BookingMainAdapter? = null
private var selectedDate = LocalDate.now()
private var vehicleId: Int? = null
private var selectedTimeslots = arrayListOf<Time>()
private var timeslotsList = listOf<TimeSlots>()


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View = binding.root

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    (activity as RentActivity).injectFragment(this, FRAGMENT_TAG)
    vehicleId = arguments?.getInt(VEHICLE_ID_KEY)
    injectFragment()
    initPresenter()
    recyclerAdapter = BookingMainAdapter(object : BookingMainAdapter.Listener {
        override fun timeslotSelect(time: Time, timeslots: List<TimeSlots>, position: Int) {
            selectedTimeslots.add(time)
            timeslots.forEachIndexed { index, vehicleTimeslots ->
                if (index != position) vehicleTimeslots.times.forEach { it.isValid = false }
                else {
                    vehicleTimeslots.times.filter { (it.position != position && it.position != position - 1 && it.position != position + 1) }
                        .forEach {
                            it.isValid = false
                        }
                    if (vehicleTimeslots.times[time.position-1].checked && vehicleTimeslots.times[time.position+1].checked) time.isValid = false
                    if (selectedTimeslots.size == 1) {
                        binding.tvBookingDescription.text = resources.getString(
                            R.string.booking_time,
                            selectedTimeslots[0].time,
                            vehicleTimeslots.times[time.position + 1].time
                        )
                    }
                    if (selectedTimeslots.isNotEmpty() && selectedTimeslots.size > 1) {
                        val starTime = selectedTimeslots.minBy { it.position }.time
                        val endTime = selectedTimeslots.maxBy { it.position }.time
                        binding.tvBookingDescription.text =
                            resources.getString(R.string.booking_time, starTime, endTime)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun timeslotRemove(time: Time, timeslots: List<TimeSlots>, position: Int) {
            selectedTimeslots.remove(time)
            if (selectedTimeslots.isEmpty()) timeslots.forEach { timeslot -> timeslot.times.forEach { time -> time.isValid = true } }
            else {
                timeslots.filter { it.position == position }.forEach { validTimeslot ->
                    validTimeslot.times.forEach {
                        if (it.position == time.position+1) if (it.isValid) it.isValid = false
                        if (it.position == time.position-1) if (it.isValid) it.isValid = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    },
        requireContext())
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.rcView.apply {
        this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        this.adapter = recyclerAdapter
    }
    vehicleId?.let { presenter?.getTimeSlots(it, selectedDate) }

    dialog?.setOnShowListener { dialog ->
        val d = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheet = d.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout
        val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        bottomSheetBehavior.apply {
            state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            isGestureInsetBottomIgnored = true
            isFitToContents = false
            skipCollapsed = true
            expandedOffset = 250
        }
    }

    class DayViewContainer(view: View) : ViewContainer(view) {
        val bind = CalendarWeekendResBinding.bind(view)
        lateinit var day: WeekDay

        fun bind(day: WeekDay) = with(bind) {
            this@DayViewContainer.day = day
            exSevenDateText.text = dateFormatter.format(day.date)
            exSevenDayText.text = day.date.dayOfWeek.displayText()
            dayBackground.showIf { day.date == selectedDate }
            dayContainer.setOnClickListener {
                dayBackground.showIf { day.date == selectedDate }
                if (selectedDate != day.date) {
                    val oldDate = selectedDate
                    selectedDate = day.date
                    binding.calendarView.notifyDateChanged(day.date)
                    oldDate?.let { binding.calendarView.notifyDateChanged(it) }
                    if (day.date != selectedDate) {
                        selectedDate = day.date
                        vehicleId?.let { vehicleId -> presenter?.getTimeSlots(vehicleId, selectedDate) }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    binding.calendarView.dayBinder = object : WeekDayBinder<DayViewContainer> {
        override fun create(view: View) = DayViewContainer(view)
        override fun bind(container: DayViewContainer, data: WeekDay) = container.bind(data)
    }

    binding.calendarView.weekScrollListener = { weekDays ->
        binding.tvCurrentMonth.text = getWeekPageTitle(weekDays)
    }

    val currentMonth = YearMonth.now()
    binding.calendarView.setup(
        currentMonth.minusMonths(5).atStartOfMonth(),
        currentMonth.plusMonths(5).atEndOfMonth(),
        firstDayOfWeekFromLocale(),
    )
    binding.calendarView.scrollToDate(LocalDate.now())

    binding.lProceedOrder.showIf { selectedTimeslots.isNotEmpty()
    }
}

private fun injectFragment() {
    activity.let { (it as BaseActivity).injectFragment(this, SubscriptionMainFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG) }
}

private fun initPresenter() {
    presenter = BookingPresenter(vehiclesInteractor).apply {
        attachView(this@BookingFragment)
        onRestoreInstance(null)
    }
}

companion object {

    val FRAGMENT_TAG = BookingFragment::javaClass.name
    const val VEHICLE_ID_KEY = "vehicle_ID"

    fun newInstance(bundle: Bundle): BookingFragment {
        val fragment = BookingFragment()
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }
}

override fun showTimeslots(timeslots: List<TimeSlots>) {
    recyclerAdapter?.submitList(timeslots)
    timeslotsList = timeslots
    binding.progressBar.hide()
}
```

Wen items of the recyclerview are minimized:
[image]

I tried to create a separate fragment with the Bottom Sheet - it doesn't work well either.

Comment: Can you post the activity code not just the design. The design is only one portion of the whole picture. It all depends on how you use the code in the MainActivity or whichever activity you are using it in

Comment: I added the Fragment code, and also changed the markup code by making it with Linear layout.

Comment: where are you calling the bottomfragment. You are showing the fragment UI and the fragment code. So if your wanting the bottom sheet fragment to be at the bottom somewhere in you UI with the frame layout you constraint is not letting it stay at the bottom. So check all your constraints and see if you have anything setting it so many X from bottom of the main UI

Comment: By the way. I open the Bottomsheetdialogfragment from a fragment where there is a Bottomsheet. Could this be the reason?

Comment: I will post an answer of how I did my fragment in my Nexus Notes which is available on the Play Store and you can see how it works. I call my bottomsheet away from the fragment it is in

Comment: Really looking forward!

Comment: When I set a specific height for the recyclerview, there is no empty space.

Answer (score 0):

This is the bottomsheet fragment and how i use it.

`bottom_sheet_fragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layoutBottomSheet"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:behavior_peekHeight="40dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<FrameLayout
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMore"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_bar"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="6.50dp"
        android:id="@+id/fNote1">

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/note_color_1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNote1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="6.50dp"
        android:id="@+id/fNote2">

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/note_color_2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNote2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="6.50dp"
        android:id="@+id/fNote4">

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/note_color_4"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNote4"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="6.50dp"
        android:id="@+id/fNote5">

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/note_color_5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNote5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="6.50dp"
        android:id="@+id/fNote6">

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/note_color_6"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNote6"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="6.50dp"
        android:id="@+id/fNote7">

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/note_color_7"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNote7"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingStart="13.00dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etNoteTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
        android:text="@string/pick_color"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etNoteTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
        android:text="@string/add_image"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutWebUrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_link"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etNoteTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
        android:text="@string/add_web_link"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutDeleteNote"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etNoteTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
        android:text="@string/delete_note"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

`create_note_fragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/notelay"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

  ......

   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMore"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/img_bar"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
   </FrameLayout>
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

These two sections work together.

`BottomSheetFragment.kt`

```
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint
 import android.app.Dialog
 import android.content.Intent
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.view.LayoutInflater
 import android.view.View
 import android.view.ViewGroup
 import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager
 import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
 import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
 import com.nerdspacesoftware.nexusnote.R
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_create_note.*
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_notes_bottom_sheet.*
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_notes_bottom_sheet.layoutImage
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_notes_bottom_sheet.layoutWebUrl

 @Suppress("ASSIGNED_BUT_NEVER_ACCESSED_VARIABLE", "DEPRECATION", "UNUSED_EXPRESSION")
  class NotesBottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
private var selectedColor = "#E53935"


companion object {
    var noteId = -1
    fun newInstance(id:Int): NotesBottomSheetFragment {
        val args = Bundle()
        val fragment = NotesBottomSheetFragment()
        fragment.arguments = args
        noteId = id
        return fragment
    }
}
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi", "InflateParams")
override fun setupDialog(dialog: Dialog, style: Int) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style)

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_bottom_sheet,null)
    dialog.run {
        setContentView(view)
    }

    val param = (view.parent as View).layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams

    val behavior = param.behavior

    if (behavior is BottomSheetBehavior<*>){
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object  : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(){
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            @SuppressLint("SwitchIntDef")
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                ""
                when (newState) {
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> {
                    }

                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> {
                        dismiss()
                        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_bottom_sheet,container,false)

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    if (noteId != -1){
        layoutDeleteNote.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }else{
        layoutDeleteNote.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    setListener()
}

private fun setListener(){
    fNote1.setOnClickListener {

        imgNote1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(0)
        selectedColor = "#4e33ff"



        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Blue")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)


    }

    fNote2.setOnClickListener {
        imgNote1.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(0)
        selectedColor = "#BAFFD105"

        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Yellow")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)

    }

    fNote4.setOnClickListener {
        imgNote1.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(0)
        selectedColor = "#ae3b76"

        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Purple")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)

    }

    fNote5.setOnClickListener {
        imgNote1.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(0)
        selectedColor = "#7CB342"

        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Green")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    fNote6.setOnClickListener {

        imgNote1.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(0)
        selectedColor = "#ff7746"
        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Orange")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    fNote7.setOnClickListener {
        imgNote1.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        selectedColor = "#000000"

        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Black")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    layoutImage.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Image")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
        dismiss()
    }
    layoutWebUrl.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","WebUrl")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
        dismiss()
    }
    layoutDeleteNote.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","DeleteNote")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
        dismiss()
    }
}
}
```

*I ran out of charachter space to continue. But this should be a good example.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the main problem is that I need to put inside the bottom sheet recyclerview. But how do I put it in the middle and insert other views on top of it.

Comment: @ge0graff follow this tutorial...   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-display-bottomsheet-on-recyclerview-item-click-with-kotlin/